# Post table React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, post, axios, fetch

I explain my problem to you, I have a table which contains several objects

under this form

```
 {id:1,title:"Campus (Pinte)", desc:"Pression - Bière Blonde - 4° Alc", detail:"Une bière blonde légère qui saura vous désaltérer comme il se doit", qty:"50 cl", img:Campus, price: 5, ctg:1, },
```

I am currently posting my entire table like this

```
postbackend = () =>{
 const config = {

method: "POST",
headers: {
  "Content-Type": "application/json",
},
 body: JSON.stringify({...this.state, items:this.props.items}),
};

const url = entrypoint + "/alluserpls"; 
fetch(url, config)
.then(res => res.json())
.then(res => {
  if (res.error) {
    alert(res.error);
  } else {
    alert(`ajouté avec l'ID ${res}!`);
  }
}).catch(e => {
  console.error(e);

}).finally(()=>this.setState({ redirect: true }));
}
```

I want to post only whatever objects do not total it from my table

for example i only want to recover title qty and price

you have an idea of ​​how to do . ? thx Neff

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As `this.props.items` is an array, you need to map over the array to create a new array with objects that have only the desired fields.

```
const newItems = this.props.items.map((item) => {
    const { title, qty, price } = item;
    return {
        title,
        qty,
        price
    };
});
```

Then use the variables however you like:

```
method: "POST",
headers: {
  "Content-Type": "application/json",
},
 body: JSON.stringify({...this.state, items: newItems }),
};
```

Comment: it does not work correctly i receive an empty array

Comment: Where do you receive the empty array? What is the structure of `this.props.items` and `this.state`?

Comment: i receive on my bdd by Mysql                                                                {id:1,title:"Campus (Pinte)", desc:"Pression - Bière Blonde - 4° Alc", detail:"Une bière blonde légère qui saura vous désaltérer comme il se doit", qty:"50 cl", img:Campus, price: 5, ctg:1, }, is the schema on JSON

Comment: @ Callum McClean structure items: [
            //Bière pression > 1 - Bières
            {id:1,title:"Campus (Pinte)", desc:"Pression - Bière Blonde - 4° Alc", detail:"Une bière blonde légère qui saura vous désaltérer comme il se doit", qty:"50 cl", img:Campus, price: 5, ctg:1, }, ]

Comment: I have updated my answer, if that doesn't work, I am not sure I understand your problem.

Comment: i have error const newItems = this.props.items.map((item) => {
    return {
        item.title,
        item.qty,
        item.price
    };
});   Parsing error: Unexpected token

Comment: @Neff I have updated again. Please accept the answer if it helps.

Comment: MacClean  
it works well thank you so much for your help

Answer (score 0):

```
    postbackend = () =>{
const { title, qty, price } = this.props.items;
const config = {

method: "POST",
headers: {
  "Content-Type": "application/json",
},
body: JSON.stringify({...this.state, items: { title, qty, price } }),
 };

 const url = entrypoint + "/alluserpls"; 
  fetch(url, config)
.then(res => res.json())
.then(res => {
  if (res.error) {
    alert(res.error);
  } else {
    alert(`film ajouté avec l'ID ${res}!`);
  }
}).catch(e => {
  console.error(e);

}).finally(()=>this.setState({ redirect: true }));
   }
```